# How much state is used for top-n queries in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm wondering how much state [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org) uses for [Top-N](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/topn/) queries and tables in general.

First, I'm using Flink SQL to process messages from a Kafka topic:

```sql
CREATE TABLE purchases (
  country STRING,
  product STRING
) WITH (
   'connector' = 'kafka',
   'topic' = 'purchases',
   'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:29092',
   'value.format' = 'json',
   'properties.group.id' = '1',
   'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset'
);
```

I also initialized a JDBC connector:

```sql
CREATE TABLE aggregations (
  `country` STRING,
  `product` STRING,
  `purchases` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country`, `product`) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'jdbc',
  'url' = 'jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres?&user=postgres&password=postgres',
  'table-name' = 'aggregations'
);
```

Finally I start the aggregation:

```sql
insert into aggregations
SELECT `country`, `product`, `purchases`
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY `purchases` DESC) AS row_num
  FROM (select country, product, count(*) as `purchases` from purchases group by country, product))
WHERE row_num <= 3;
```

From Flink state management [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/concepts/overview/) is says:

> Conceptually, source tables are never kept entirely in state. An implementer deals with logical tables (i.e. dynamic tables). Their state requirements depend on the used operations.

So do I understand correctly that Flink doesn't save the rows of `purchases` table from Kafka connector?

More importantly, in aggregation:

```sql
select country, product, count(*) as `purchases` from purchases group by country, product
```

does Flink keep every country, product key in state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink will convert SQL/Table API into DataStream/DataSet operators. E.g. for the `purchases` table in SQL, it will be converted into `FlinkKafkaConsumer` in DataStream.

You are right. Flinks does not save the data from Flink into state, but instead, saving Kafka offset into state.

For the `select and group by` statement, yes, Flink will save the keys and values(count) in states.

Answer (score 2):

When using Flink SQL or Table API, your incoming stream is transformed into a dynamic table. Your top-n is a continuous query, which accumulates state. This is explained in more detail at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/concepts/dynamic_tables/

Your Top-N query accumulates state, as explained on https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/topn/. There's also the Window Top-N, as explained at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-topn/. The latter mentions `Moreover, window Top-N purges all intermediate state when no longer needed.`. The Window Top-N is more state friendly compared to the Top-N.